# What is entry point of BigQuery Cloud Function?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I successfully updated a BigQuery Table Using an External API and a Cloud Function. My entry point of the code below is hello_pubsub, however, I do not know what those 2 parameters are. I didn't provide event and context to the function, how can it still run my code without errors? Though I know the code in the function provide all the information to do the loading job.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from google.cloud import bigquery

def hello_pubsub(event, context):

    PROJECT = "test-391108"

    client = bigquery.Client(project=PROJECT)
    
    table_id = "test-391108.TEAM.MEMBER"

    API_ENDPOINT ='https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/'

    response = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, timeout=5)
    response_json = response.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(response_json['teams'])
    df = df.iloc[:,:6]

    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE")
    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_id, job_config=job_config)
```

Is there also another way I can schedule my code without using function and load data into Bigquery table by using an External API?

Comment: The two variables event and context are what is expected when you set up a PubSub trigger.  If you want a URL you can post to, use an example with a HTTP trigger and that will automatically set up a URL, and have a single response object in the sample method.  It's an option when you first create a function.

Answer (score 1):

Posting @[Mike Karp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1196131/mike-karp)'s comment as an answer for better visibility for the community.

> The two variables event and context are what is expected when you set up a PubSub trigger

For reference a definition of the variables are cited here:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-event-driven-functions#background-functions